# ACF: Display Google Map in frontend issues

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I have a CTP with an ACF Google Map field. The values in this field come from somewhere external via APIs.

I set the API right because in backend I see correctly longitude, latitude and address and the Google Map works.

However when I try to render the map in frontend following [this](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/) guide, what I get is a map with no marker and with wrong longitude and latitude (somewhere in the ocean).

In my functions.php file I have this

```
//GOOGLE MAPS API KEY
function my_acf_init() {
     
    acf_update_setting('google_api_key', 'MY_API_KEY');
}
 
add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
```

In my CPT Template I have this

```
<style type="text/css">
.acf-map {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
border: #ccc solid 1px;
margin: 20px 0;
}

// Fixes potential theme css conflict.
.acf-map img {
   max-width: inherit !important;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {

/**
 * initMap
 *
 * Renders a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
 *
 * @date    22/10/19
 * @since   5.8.6
 *
 * @param   jQuery $el The jQuery element.
 * @return  object The map instance.
 */
function initMap( $el ) {

// Find marker elements within map.
var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

// Create gerenic map.
var mapArgs = {
    zoom        : $el.data('zoom') || 16,
    mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], mapArgs );

// Add markers.
map.markers = [];
$markers.each(function(){
    initMarker( $(this), map );
});

// Center map based on markers.
centerMap( map );

// Return map instance.
return map;
}

/**
 * initMarker
 *
 * Creates a marker for the given jQuery element and map.
 *
 * @date    22/10/19
 * @since   5.8.6
 *
 * @param   jQuery $el The jQuery element.
 * @param   object The map instance.
 * @return  object The marker instance.
 */
function initMarker( $marker, map ) {

// Get position from marker.
var lat = $marker.data('lat');
var lng = $marker.data('lng');
var latLng = {
    lat: parseFloat( lat ),
    lng: parseFloat( lng )
};

// Create marker instance.
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : latLng,
    map: map
});

// Append to reference for later use.
map.markers.push( marker );

// If marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow.
if( $marker.html() ){

    // Create info window.
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: $marker.html()
    });

    // Show info window when marker is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open( map, marker );
    });
}
}

/**
 * centerMap
 *
 * Centers the map showing all markers in view.
 *
 * @date    22/10/19
 * @since   5.8.6
 *
 * @param   object The map instance.
 * @return  void
 */
function centerMap( map ) {

// Create map boundaries from all map markers.
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
map.markers.forEach(function( marker ){
    bounds.extend({
        lat: marker.position.lat(),
        lng: marker.position.lng()
    });
});

// Case: Single marker.
if( map.markers.length == 1 ){
    map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );

// Case: Multiple markers.
} else{
    map.fitBounds( bounds );
}
}

// Render maps on page load.
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.acf-map').each(function(){
    var map = initMap( $(this) );
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

And this is how I am trying to render the map in front end

```
<?php 
    $location = get_field('map');
    if( $location ): ?>
        <div class="acf-map" data-zoom="16">
            <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo esc_attr($location['lat']); ?>" data-lng="<?php echo esc_attr($location['lng']); ?>"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This is my ACF Field. The filed name is “map”

```
<?php $map = get_field( 'map' ); ?>
<?php if ( $map ) : ?>
<?php echo $map['address']; ?>
<?php echo $map['lat']; ?>
<?php echo $map['lng']; ?>
<?php echo $map['zoom']; ?>
<?php $optional_data_keys = array('street_number', 'street_name', 'city', 'state', 'post_code', 'country'); ?>
<?php foreach ( $optional_data_keys as $key ) : ?>
    <?php if ( isset( $map[ $key ] ) ) : ?>
        <?php echo $map[ $key ]; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any hint? :D

Comment: I think you need to debug your script. Try adding console.log()s for $marker after you initialise it, then in initMarker() to check that's getting run properly, then in centreMap() for each time you extend bounds and the final value of bounds. And possibly the return values of map.setCenter() or map.fitBounds() if they have them.

Comment: Which jquety version are you using? $('xyz').data() only works from 1.4.3 on